# Order / Invoice - Prefix "16-" NOT POSSIBLE?

Tags: orders, invoice, sql, increment-id, prefix

I need to customize my prefix for the order / invoice ID´s. 
So my order number should look like this: 16-0001
I need the year as prefix with an "-". But when I try this:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store SET increment_prefix = 16-, increment_last_id = '16-00000' WHERE store_id = 1 AND entity_type_id = 5; # orders
```

I get an mysql error. So can anybody say how i do this or it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store SET increment_prefix = '16-', increment_last_id = '16-00000' WHERE store_id = 1 AND entity_type_id = 5; # orders
```

The prefix is a string and should be enclosed in quotes. `16-` is parsed as "number sixteen" + "minus" which does not make sense without a second argument.